# Prevent Safari from auto-completing a URL incorrectly?

Tags: safari

Whenever I try to type `plus.google.com` into Safari, it starts auto-completing the URL to `plus.url.google.com`. I've tried removing all my of vists to this domain from my history hoping that `plus.google.com` would be what it auto-completes with, but that doesn't seem to help.

How do I get rid of `plus.url.google.com` and have Safari auto-complete to `plus.google.com`?

Answer (score 1):

There are three main sources for Safari's auto-complete:

- History
- Bookmarks
- iCloud Tabs

Clearing the URL from your history is not enough — make sure that plus.url.google.com does not appear in any of your bookmarks or any iCloud tab. Once a URL does not appear any of these places, relaunch Safari.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to use a keyboard shortcut to remove the incorrect auto entry.

Highlight the incorrect entry like the:

> plus.url.google.com

and pres <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>